# wp_list_pages - show pages immediately 1 level below current level

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

I'm setting up an events page in a wordpress site I'm building.

Let's take a look at the page menu hierarchy:

First of all there is a Events landing page. It will display four regions where events are held. Inside the region are the events.

[image: Menu example]

This page is working as intended. The problem arrises when you click through to these pages and what is now shown.

When you click through to a region, I want a list of the events in that specific region to be shown. For example if you are on the page of region 2, I want all the events in region 2 listed.

I've made sure I've set this up correctly in the backend, with parent pages and such.

I'm using an example taken from the codex of wp_list_pages and I have created a new events template and created a new sidebar for the events template. I have added this within the sidebar of the events template (sorry a bit of a mouthful!):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&depth=1");
else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
 class="icon-something"></i>');
if ($children) { ?>
<ul class="submenu-children">
  <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This code is currently showing a list of pages on the same level as the page. So if I'm on Region 1, it shows all the regions and nothing else. I want to be able to see the Events if I'm on a Region. I'm thinking this may be the wrong chunk of code I'm looking for and perhaps below is more what I need to go with? (child of).

```
<ul>
<?php
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&show_date=modified
&date_format=$date_format'); ?>
</ul>
```

If anyone has any better ways or creating this kind of menu hierarchy I would love to hear how you would approach this. Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Events landing page" is a proper WordPress "Page", which I assume it is, then I think that all you need is:

```
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&depth=1");
```

1. On the landing page, you should get the four regions
2. On a regions page you should get the regions children
3. On the individual child pages you'd get nothing

I am not sure if #3 is what you want but #1 and #2 are correct, if I understand the question.